# bazel rules cc no such target @platforms//os:wasi: target 'wasi' was not declared in package 'os'

Tags: bazel, re2

I am trying to build a c++ binary using bazel rules_cc. I'm on debian linux stable x86_64.  I am using git_repository() rule to download the RE2 library and I get an error while building.

The usage and error is

```
$ bazel build //mytesty:main
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: While resolving configuration keys for @RE2//:re2: no such target '@platforms//os:wasi': target 'wasi' not declared in package 'os' defined by /home/davis/.cache/bazel/_bazel_davis/810a2cc77a9a6b5312233b083c966cb8/external/platforms/os/BUILD
ERROR: Analysis of target '//mytesty:main' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.590s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (17 packages loaded, 27 targets configured)
```

I'm trying to use the git_repository() rule to pull down the RE2 git repo.  Here is the relevant info from the WORKSPACE file.

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
git_repository(
    name = "RE2",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/re2.git",
    commit = "5723bb8950318135ed9cf4fc76bed988a087f536"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`wasi` is defined here:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/platforms/blob/da5541f26b7de1dc8e04c075c99df5351742a4a2/os/BUILD#L101

and that was added some time ago in Nov 2020:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/platforms/commit/ed46070dfc79646c573acede7c4f9257d3d8fe44

You may need to update to a more recent version of `platforms`.

Comment: Cool. Many thanks.  How do you update platforms?

Comment: I had assumed that one needed a rule in the WORKSPACE file to get `@platforms`, but it seems that there's an `@platforms` bundled within bazel. So if you can update your version of bazel to the latest, then you should get `wasi` in `@platforms`. If for whatever reason you can't update bazel, then you can also add a WORKSPACE rule with the name `platforms` to override the bundled platforms.

Comment: It took me awhile, but I built bazel from source and with latest release.  It works as you pointed out. Thanks a bunch. I appreciate your help and expertise!